# Search Center on SharePoint Publishing site

Tags: sharepoint, search, moss

Can someone give me some directions on how to setup SharePoint Search Center so I can get results from the list and that they have some custom (modified) link?

I have Forms authentication (and anonymous access) enabled with alternate access mapping.

Right now in the Default zone I get results from the data in lists and they all point to the AllItems.aspx. If try search from the Internet zone I don't get any results from the lists and I am guessing that this is because of some security settings. But if make them to show how will I customize resulting link so that list items are shown with some publishing page.
For example if I keep news in the News list and when I do search I want to get result with link in following format

```
http://somesite/Pages/News.aspx?itemId=12
```

where the itemID is he id of the news item.

Can I customize link in the result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the result link using the Core Search Results web part.  It is all in the XSL which is available if you modify the shared properties of the web part.

The problem is that this page is meant to show search results of all types including documents in SharePoint, files potentially outside of SharePoint, web pages, business data, etc.

You may want to have a custom search results page that uses a specific scope or managed property query such that you can be sure the results will be list items.  This can probably be done without any coding (if you don't consider XSL coding) and you could still use the Core Search Results web part.

Another option may be similar, but use the Data Form/View web part (through SharePoint Designer) or the Content Query Web Part (Publishing Infrastructure feature required).